# PHP refuses to run in subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, opensuse

```
cat /etc/issue
Welcome to openSUSE 12.1 "Asparagus" - Kernel \r (\l).
```

When Apache serves me `/srv/www/htdocs/phpinfo.php` I get the expected output, but if I move it to `/srv/www/htdocs/test/phpinfo.php` suddenly Apache serves me the PHP code directly in the browser, like Apache doesn't recognize (or more likely, ignores) that it's PHP code at all.

What can I do to troubleshoot this? I've tried googling around a bit and I'm fairly certain it has to do with the Apache settings, but I don't know where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I experience this problem before on Ubuntu server, and created a blog post about it for my reference, I think you are experiencing the same problem in your mods_available.

Here is the blog post, please let me know what you get after trying it http://www.anchorx.com/ali/2011/02/23/ubuntu-server-not-pasring-php/

Comment: Your answer did help, even though the blog post did not apply. I went into `/etc/apache2/conf.d/php5.conf`, and changed `<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[345]?|tml)$">` to `<FilesMatch ".ph(p[345]?|tml)$">` (removed the \) -- and suddenly, subdirectories work. I hope this isn't bad practice, but at least it works now.

Comment: The post is about ubuntu, and similar to your issue, I am glad it got resolved:) cheers, cant advice about the practice as I don't have enough experience with openSUSE file structure.. cheers!

Comment: Hm, I must have misjudged, the issue seems to be back :( strange.

Comment: Why would it be in the error log? Parsing PHP as HTML is not an error.